# testing rails+backbone application with rspec & capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, rspec, capybara

I'm writing a tests for my app with listed gems. I couldn't find how to set Capybara to work with backbone (ajax in all)
example test:

```
require 'spec_helper' describe "Main" do   describe "GET /" do
    it "displays articles" do
      Article.create!(title:'title',body:'<p>body text</p>')
      visit '/'
      page.should have_content('body text')
    end   
  end 
end
```

and output of the test:

```
Failures:

  1) Main GET / displays articles
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content('body text')
       expected there to be text "body text" in "Loading..."
     # ./spec/features/main_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

"Loading..." is the pre ajax text in my view template...

The point is that I don't want to use Jasmine at the moment for this app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are running Capybara with the default Rack::Test driver, which means no JavaScript. Rack::Test loads your app in process and fakes a browser DOM behind the Capybara API.

You need to use a driver that runs your tests in a real Web browser. There are a few different options: a Selenium driver comes with Capybara and runs your tests in a real browser (normally Firefox), others are implemented in separate gems, such as [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) which uses PhantomJS and the headless WebKit browser.

There are instructions on the Capybara [readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver) about setting up the right driver. You can switch a group of tests to use a JavaScript supporting driver by adding the `js` option to a describe block, e.g.:

```
describe "Main with JavaScript", :js => true do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: This http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/   may help you